# Page requested not found

Tags: facebook

I recently created a new app and added it to an existing page using the following:
http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=APP_ID&pages=1&page=PAGE_ID

Now randomly when i am logged in and go to my page i get the following error:
The page you requested was not found. 
You may have clicked an expired link or mistyped the address. Some web addresses are case sensitive.

Has anyone else found the same issue? 
I have been reading some posts and i think it might have to do with the way the app was added to my page. Not entirely sure though.

HELP :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's connected to how you added it but here is another option to add app to page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL
```

Change YOUR_URL with the url in app settings Page Tab URL.

Comment: my app is already successfully added to my page (www.facebook.com/champmoves), do you think i should do the add app page again as per your above comment?

Comment: I just added another way of addin tab to page. You said you've read this might be the problem.

Comment: hmmm its definitely a strange one. have you heard of this problem before?